# How to remove space after Transform.translate in CustomScrollView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Help me, any idea how to remove the space between yellow and green Container?
It's caused by the Container have additional height after transform translate.

I need CustomSrollView with SliverAppBar and a child below it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Example(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(slivers: [
      SliverSafeArea(
        top: false,
        sliver: SliverAppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
          floating: true,
          toolbarHeight: 0,
          bottom: const PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(30), child: Text("AppBar")),
        ),
      ),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: const Offset(0.0, -30.0),
          child: Container(height: 500, color: Colors.yellow),
        ),
      ),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Align(child: Container(height: 500, color: Colors.green))),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: did you managed to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you want to move the yellow container, but you don't want to take  translate spaces the space. I don't know what design you are doing, I may just reduce the height in this case. Or use padding in extra spaces.

According to the question, we can use stack like.

```
 SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            height: 500 + 500,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 500,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 500 - 30,
                  child: Transform.translate(
                    offset: const Offset(0.0, -30.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 500,
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

But in this case we are overlapping with green container.

We can

- reduce the size,
- use stack, will overlap with green container

Comment: In my question is also important how to place the SliverToBoxAdapter below SliverAppBar

Comment: Yes, this answer works in that manner, add `SliverAppBar` the way you did on question.

Comment: When i scroll its fine, but the initial position is wrong. Its there a gap under the appabar.

Comment: That is because i alligend with TopCenter. use Positioned top: appBar hegiht. 

Can you add 2 images, one while there is no scroll, 2nd while scroll?

Comment: [Your inital top position is](https://imgur.com/1u57vmX)
[then](https://imgur.com/aKM3vbf)

[My initial top position is](https://imgur.com/7XR8AeW)

Comment: is that what you want to archive?

Comment: My initial position is fine but unfortunately I recaive additional space on bottom after transform translate. Is there any widget that I can wrap the Transform.translate and reduce height from bottom?

Comment: you like to have yellow container bellow appbar on init?